# iOS NSUserDefaults plist files are losing changes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, plist, reset

We are facing an unusual scenario where my app's plist get set to default values automatically ,mostly after restarting the ipad/iphone. Any ideas on why this happening?

We are reading the plist like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[AppSetting globalConfig]];

+ (NSDictionary *) globalConfig {
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    return [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] autorelease];
}
```

And after saving we write it off with

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
[defaults setBool:self.isLogIn forKey:@"isLogin"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

some more edits...
does this have any thing to do with this automatic restore. i am seeing this line in the ipads who's plist was  restored..

```
<Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'appName' access to protected services is denied.
<Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appName' access to protected services is denied.
```

Comment: You need to add more detail to your post for anyone to understand what you're asking. Please see the "How to Ask" section in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @0x7fffffff i dont have much details on why its occurring , so the said details is all i have.. At least have the courtesy of not downvoting..

Comment: I'll bet two details you have are what the plist is for and where it is stored.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner ya i have that info and based on that i was able to tell that plist was restored to default state. and all the login information on that file was gone..

Comment: The answer to your question is no because something like this is not logical. Check you interaction between you version control server and xcode may be it's resetting it. Your plist file is synced every-time you run code via xcode and resetting your device is certainly not connected with it.

Comment: @KunalBalani thanks for your input..This was happing on client side ipads.. mostly after they switch off the ipad in night and restart in next morning.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner The one in the preference folder where. we just use it to keep the app information like whether the user is logged in or not .. 
We read the values by NSUserDefault and save it back.

Comment: @rhlnair you need to elaborate more , how can you confirm this ? Is there a property which has been modified ? How are you so sure that plist file is modified ?

Answer (score 1):

Your app is writing to NSUserDefaults without ever calling `synchronize` .  The app goes to the background, and crashes for some reason (or just crashes outright) - so the changes meant to be saved to NSUserDefaults never are, and it appears your plist file is reverting when it was just never saved.  It could be powering off the devices kill the apps in a way that is not allowing the save of NSUserDefaults changes.

OR are you writing to the NSUserDefaults plist files without going through NSUserDefaults?  Don't do that.

OR the testers are testing on multiple devices with the same iCloud account on both that are synchronizing the UserDefaults plist files between devices for your app.

Edit: Why are you reading settings from the read-only app bundle and using `NSUserDefaults` to save changes?  They will not do the same thing.  You will never be reading wheat `NSUserDefaults` is writing to.

Comment: first i would like to thank you .. but we are doing the way you suggested.

Comment: Added one more idea, if not that I don't know why.

Comment: i really doubt the second theory.. any suggestion how i should make sure that this is the problem..

Comment: i will investigate the iCloud theory.. thanks for the help..

Comment: Does it reset at reboot or (as i suppose) as you run the app? it looks like you are initializing NSUserDefaults to setting.plist at each app startup

Comment: @LucaRocchi yes it reset after reboot (followed by starting the app) which occurs in rare case for some users.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner do <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'appName' access to protected services is denied.
<Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appName' access to protected services is denied. have anything to do with this issues ??

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner I havent written any code for iCloud sync. I am wondering will it occur automatically?

Comment: Sorry, not sure in either case.  I think the sync could happen automatically.  I updated the answer after seeing your code - ALWAYS PROVIDE CODE if possible.